# how to generate a designated function in assembly file by xcode

Tags: xcode, assembly, llvm

I need to call a function in xcode6.1 write by asm in file asm_add.s, and I set file type as "llvm assembly":

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.align  4
.arm
.globl  _asm_add

_asm_add:
    sub sp, #0x1c
    add r0, r1
    add sp, #0x1c
    bl r14
```

and I called it in file case_arm_pcs.c like this:

```
int asm_add(int a, int b);
void caller()
{
    int a = 1; 
    int b = 2;
    int c = asm_add(a, b);
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

But when I built it, met a link error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_asm_add", referenced from:
      _caller in case_arm_pcs.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z8_asm_addi)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I guess it's the compiler's reason, but I don't know in detail and how to resovle it.

Comment: Maybe `.arm` needs to be `.armv7` ?

Comment: I don't speak arm, but if this were x86, I'd be thinking that you were compiling case_arm_pcs.c as c++ (which causes name mangling).  Perhaps you could try declaring the function with `extern "C" { int asm_add(int a, int b); }`?

Comment: I changed case_arm_pcs.c into case_arm_pcs.mm, compile it as objective-c++, and change asm_add.s into  Assembly type, then it works correctly.

Comment: Also, it need extern "C";